# HttpServletRequest headers disappear when using CompletableFuture

Tags: java, asynchronous, servlets, completable-future

Firstly, my apologies for such a vague question title. I am new to asynchronous programming in Java (and thus **CompletableFuture**) and I am trying to play around with it using Spring's `@Async` feature.

I have the following **AsyncConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class AsyncConfiguration {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(AsyncConfiguration.class);

    @Bean("asyncExecutor")
    public Executor asyncExecutor() {

        LOG.info("Configuring ASYNC Executor");

        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(1);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(2);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("AsyncThread--");
        executor.initialize();

        LOG.info("ASYNC Executor Configuration Complete");

        return executor;
    }

}
```

Now I have two filters, **ApiUsageLimitFilter** with `@Order(1)` and **RequestResponseLoggingFilter** with `@Order(2)`

In the `doFilter` of `ApiUsageLimitFilter.java`, I have the following code:

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        LOG.info("API Filter Request handled by Thread {} -> {}", Thread.currentThread().getName(),
                Thread.currentThread().getId());
        final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = HttpServletRequest.class.cast(request);
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = HttpServletResponse.class.cast(response);
        try {
            LOG.info("Checking usgae limit for IP: {}", httpServletRequest.getHeader("X-Real-IP"));
            apiUsageMonitorService.isAllowed(httpServletRequest)  //Some method that returns a CompletableFuture<Boolean>
            .thenCompose((allowed) -> {
                if (allowed.equals(Boolean.TRUE)) {
                    LOG.info("IP: {} allowed", httpServletRequest.getHeader("X-Real-IP")); // Value is NULL
                    try {
                        chain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
                    } catch (IOException | ServletException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                } else {
                    LOG.warn("IP: {} reached its usage limit. Blocking any further calls",
                            httpServletRequest.getHeader("X-Real-IP"));
                    return apiUsageMonitorService.remainingTTL(httpServletRequest);
                }
            }).thenAccept((remainingTTL) -> {

                System.out.println("This gets executed");
                if (remainingTTL != null) {
                    System.out.println("SOme of this gets executed");
                    try {

                        ApiResponse errorResponse = new ApiResponse();
                        errorResponse.setStatus(ApiRequestStatus.FAILURE);
                        errorResponse.setMessage(
                                "You have reached the API usage limit. Only 10 requests allowed per hour. Please try after the time specified in Retry-After header");
                        errorResponse.setErrorCode(ApiRequestErrorCode.API_USAGE_LIMIT_REACHED);
                        String errorResponseString = getResponseAsString(errorResponse);
                        LOG.info("Error response as String:{}", errorResponseString);
                        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS.value());

                        Long remainingSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(remainingTTL);
                        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Retry-After", remainingSeconds.toString() + " seconds");
                        httpServletResponse.getWriter().write(errorResponseString);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }

                }
            });
```

The above method calls a service that basically returns a **CompletableFuture** of `boolean` and on the basis of that value, I either call the next filter in chain or I return a response back.

What's happening is that before the call goes to `apiUsageMonitorService.isAllowed(httpServletRequest)` line, the request object exists and I can see the header in. However, when inside `thenCompose` of the `apiUsageMonitorService.isAllowed(httpServletRequest)` method, which returns a `CompletableFuture`, I cannot see that header value **X-Real-IP** anymore. It prints a null.

I tried the same without async code and I was able to access the request header even after that particular call. Moreover, the call was going to the next filter in the chain as well. But when using `CompletableFuture`, the header simply doesn't exist at that point after the call and it also doesn't go to the `RequestResponseLoggingFilter`, which is the next filter in the chain, because I don't see any logs done by that filter.

Below are the logs:

2020-02-23 23:12:53.721  INFO 28774 --- [nio-8080-exec-3]

```
i.turls.lib.filters.ApiUsageLimitFilter  : API Filter Request handled by Thread http-nio-8080-exec-3 -> 58
2020-02-23 23:12:53.721  INFO 28774 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] i.turls.lib.filters.ApiUsageLimitFilter  : Checking usgae limit for IP: 122.168.23.274
2020-02-23 23:12:53.721  INFO 28774 --- [ AsyncThread--1] i.t.l.s.i.ApiUsageMonitorServiceImpl     : Running Async Method on Thread AsyncThread--1 -> 70
2020-02-23 23:12:53.721  INFO 28774 --- [ AsyncThread--1] i.t.l.s.i.ApiUsageMonitorServiceImpl     : Checking API usage for IP: 122.168.23.274
2020-02-23 23:12:53.729  INFO 28774 --- [ AsyncThread--1] i.t.l.s.i.ApiUsageMonitorServiceImpl     : Creating new entry with IP 122.168.23.274
2020-02-23 23:12:53.738  INFO 28774 --- [ AsyncThread--1] i.turls.lib.filters.ApiUsageLimitFilter  : IP: null allowed
```

What's going wrong here? Is it that when the `CompletableFuture` finishes, the request object is long gone because the Filters implement a synchronous method? If so, how do I take care of this issue? I have to use it the async way

Comment: Have you tried to get header value before calling async lambda? Anyway, I'm afraid you'll need to call request.getAsyncContext() and implement AsyncListener to make async logic work.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use Spring's `RequestContextHolder`.

> Holder class to expose the web request in the form of a thread-bound RequestAttributes object. The request will be inherited by any child threads spawned by the current thread if the inheritable flag is set to true.

The following snippet (used) to work for me, but its a few years old now.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
if (requestAttributes instanceof WebRequest) {
    WebRequest request = (WebRequest) requestAttributes;

    Iterator<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();

    while (headerNames.hasNext()) {

        String headerName = headerNames.next();
        String[] headerValues = request.getHeaderValues(headerName);
        Arrays.stream(headerValues)
            .forEach(headerValue -> headers.add(headerName, headerValue));
    }
}
```